# Is there a way to use LaTeX packages in the exams2canvas of R/exams?

Tags: canvas, latex, tikz, r-exams

I'm trying to setup up an exam using R/exams, using the function `exams2canvas()`. My questions contain LaTeX code that requires to use some packages (in particular `tikz` and `tikz-qtree` and a few other `tikz` libraries) but I cannot figure out how to import them.

To create a pdf, I manually modified the tex template (`plain.tex`) in the exams package of R, by adding the following two lines:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
```

Could I perhaps modify the canvas file in a similar way? Is there another way that I can use LaTeX packages in `exams2canvas()`?

---

Minimal example:

```
\begin{question}
\Tree[.S [.NP [.D the ] [.N children ] ] [.VP [.V study ] ]  [.NP [.N books ] ]  ]
\begin{answerlist}
  \item 0.7
  \item 0.2
  \item 0.1
\end{answerlist}
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
\begin{answerlist}
  \item False
  \item False
  \item True
\end{answerlist}
\end{solution}

\exname{Trees}
\extype{schoice}
\exsolution{001}
```

Comment: Can you make a [mre]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that for Canvas output, just like for other HTML-based formats, the LaTeX code needs to be converted to HTML. And the HTML converters we use (`tth` and `pandoc`) both just support a limited number of LaTeX commands beyond the base LaTeX distribution.

Thus, you need to compile `tikz` graphics in LaTeX and then convert them to a graphics format supported by HTML, e.g., SVG vector graphics or alternatively raster graphics such as PNG or JPG. This functionality is offered by the `include_tikz()` function in R/exams.

I have modified your exercise so that the `tikz` code is only included as LaTeX for `exams2pdf()` and `exams2nops()` - which then need to be adapted to load `tikz` and `tikz-qtree`. Otherwise, the `tikz` code is rendered to SVG for which `magick` plus `pdf2svg` is used. Alternatively, you could also render to PNG, for example.

So you can do:

```
exams2html("tikz_tree.Rnw")
```

or

```
exams2nops("tikz_tree.Rnw", usepackage = c("tikz", "tikz-qtree"))
```

etc.

`exams2canvas()` will work like `exams2html()`. The modified `tikz_tree.Rnw` file is included at the end of the post. Some further pointers and details (including an R/Markdown version of the exercise) are available in this discussion in the R/exams forum on R-Forge: https://R-Forge.R-project.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=33909&forum_id=4377&group_id=1337

Some similar but more elaborate exercise templates are available on the R/exams web page:
http://www.R-exams.org/templates/automaton/
http://www.R-exams.org/templates/logic/

#### `tikz_tree.Rnw`

```
<<echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=
## determine the output type depending on exams2xyz interface:
## - plain .tex for exams2pdf, exams2nops which then need to use packages tikz and tikz-qtree
## - .svg for other HTML-based interfaces
typ <- if(match_exams_call() %in% c("exams2pdf", "exams2nops")) "tex" else "svg"

## TikZ code (note that backslashes need to be escaped"
tikz_tree <- "\\Tree[.S [.NP [.D the ] [.N children ] ] [.VP [.V study ] ]  [.NP [.N books ] ]  ]"
@

\begin{question}

<<echo=FALSE, results=tex>>=
include_tikz(tikz_tree, name = "tik_tree", format = typ,
  packages = "tikz-qtree", width = "5cm")
@

\begin{answerlist}
  \item 0.4
  \item 0.2
  \item 0.9
\end{answerlist}
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
\begin{answerlist}
  \item False
  \item False
  \item True
\end{answerlist}
\end{solution}

\exname{Tree}
\extype{schoice}
\exsolution{001}
```